# I have a Google Service Account, how do I use C# on server side to send an email?

Tags: c#, gmail, blazor, google-workspace, service-accounts

I have a Blazor application.  I'd like to send an email from the server side (for example, when a user registers).  I have setup a service account within my gmail organization and have a user in my organization that will be the 'from' address.  Can someone point me at the right documentation for this use case?  Or an example?  I do not want any popup/web authentication step.  (The email is sent from the server side, with no GUI.)

(I recognize this as a potentially vague question... I'm not sure what to ask, and the support docs suggested using stack overflow.  *shrug*)

Comment: It seems that you have [wasted 6 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233694/gmail-api-can-i-send-email-using-the-service-account). Sorry, happens in our job

Comment: Use the [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) package to use the SMTP protocol to send messages. But know this: you may be better off using a mail service provider than trying to hit a Google-operated SMTP server directly. They make it hard to keep spamsters out. Sendgrid has a reasonable service, and there are others.

Comment: Thanks both.  I used to use SendGrid.  Then after about a year off, they disabled my account and there seems to be no customer service to help.  Ho-hum... I'll figure something out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69612942/1841839

Comment: Service Accounts are part of Google Cloud. Google Cloud does not provide email services. You will need to use a mail service to send mail. You can use Google Workspace and Domain Wide Delegation but that is the wrong approach. I recommend using a mail service that supports your use case (machine generated email).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## gmail api option.

In order to use service accounts with your workspace domain you need to set up the service account and enable [domain wide deligation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings)

Google has sevral very good guidles on how to set it up.  The best IMO being[Perform Google Workspace Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)

You will just need to rember to set the scope  `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail`, instead of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user`, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group` shown in the example

After that its simply a matter of using the standard service account code and adding the user that you wish to deligate as

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath)
                         .CreateScoped(scopes);
var gsuiteUser = "noreply@yourdomain.com";   
    
var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });
```

This is a previous question related to this.  [How to use gmail api with service accounts or google Oauth in C# for sending mails?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69612942/1841839) However im not sure if you are looking for a smtp answer or a Gmail api answer.

## smtp / imap option.

If you want to go though the SMTP / IMAP you need to check [Xoauth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol). The procedure is the same you will need to set up domain wide delegation to your domain account but the scope changes you need to use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.imap_admin`

I am not aware of any .net examples of this.

Comment: I finally got it working, and it was similar enough to this that I will accept it.  I also had to add this: 
```
                GoogleCredential googleCred = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                        .CreateScoped(Scopes)
                        .CreateWithUser(from_email_addr);
```